# Jasmine spec for a throttled computed attribute

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, jasmine

I'm trying to write a jasmine spec for a computed observable like below:

```
self.positionDate = ko.computed(function () {
  var dateString = "";
  var start = moment(self.positionStartDate()).format("LL");
  var end = moment(self.positionEndDate()).format("LL");
  if (start !== end) {
    dateString = sprintf("%s - %s", start, end);
  }
  else {
    dateString = sprintf("%s", start);
  }
  return dateString;
}).extend({ throttle: 1 });
```

With the throttle, the positionDate computed function is not getting updated.  I've tried artificially waiting as well as calling valueHasMutated() both to no avail.

Has anyone successfully written a spec on a throttled computed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the usage of the `throttle` you made your observable "async" so you need to use the [asynchronous specs features](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/wiki/Asynchronous-specs) in Jasmine.

So you need to use the `runs` and `waits` functions something like:

```
describe('throttled obserable', function () {

    it('positionDate should be changed after positionStartDate changed', 
      function () {
        var vm = new ViewModel();

        runs(function () {
            vm.positionStartDate('January 21 2013');
            vm.positionEndDate('January 22 2013');
        });

        waits(1);

        runs(function () {
            expect(vm.positionDate())
                 .toEqual('January 21 2013 - January 22 2013');
            vm.positionStartDate('January 20 2013');
        });

        waits(1);

        runs(function () {
            expect(vm.positionDate())
                 .toEqual('January 20 2013 - January 22 2013');
        });
    });
});
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nemesv/ZNAFa/4/).